# Parallel.ForEach Source List with Where Condition

Tags: c#, concurrency, parallel-processing, race-condition, parallel.foreach

I have a code block which processes StoreProducts an then adds or updates them in the database in a for each loop. But this is slow. When I convert the code Parallel.ForEach block, then same products gets both added and updated at the same time. I could not figure out how to safely utilize for the following functionality, any help would be appreciated.

```
var validProducts = storeProducts.Where(p => p.Price2 > 0
                                                     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.ProductAtt08Desc.Trim())
                                                     && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Barcode.Trim()) 
            ).ToList();

var processedProductCodes = new List<string>();

var po = new ParallelOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
        };

Parallel.ForEach(validProducts.Where(p => !processedProductCodes.Contains(p.ProductCode)), po,
            (product) =>
{
            lock (_lockThis)
            {
                processedProductCodes.Add(product.ProductCode);
            }

    // Check if Product Exists in Db

    // if product is not in Db Add to Db

    // if product is in Db Update product in Db

}
```

The thing in here is, the list validProducts may have more than one same ProductCode, so they are variants and I have to manage that even one of them is being processed it should not be processed again.

So where condition that is found in the parallel foreach 'validProducts.Where(p => !processedProductCodes.Contains(p.ProductCode)' is not working as expected like in normal for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach` buffers items internally for each thread, one option you could do is switch to a partitioner that does not use buffering

```
var pat = Partitioner.Create(validProducts.Where(p => !processedProductCodes.Contains(p.ProductCode))
                            ,EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);

Parallel.ForEach(pat, po, (product) => ...
```

That will get you closer but you will still have a race conditions where two of the same object can be processed because you don't break out of the loop if you find a duplicate.

The better option is switch `processedProductCodes` to a `HashSet<string>` and change your code to

```
var processedProductCodes = new HashSet<string>();

var po = new ParallelOptions()
        {
            MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4
        };

Parallel.ForEach(validProducts, po,
            (product) =>
{
            //You can safely lock on processedProductCodes
            lock (processedProductCodes)
            {
                if(!processedProductCodes.Add(product.ProductCode))
                {
                    //Add returns false if the code is already in the collection.
                    return;
                }
            }

    // Check if Product Exists in Db

    // if product is not in Db Add to Db

    // if product is in Db Update product in Db

}
```

HashSet has a much faster lookup and is built in to the `Add` function.

Comment: You may also want to look at performing an 'insert or update' query instead of checking your in-memory list.  In databases that do not support this directly, you can usually perform an update, check # of affected records, and insert if 0 all in a single query.  But I would be very worried about the DB blocking/deadlocking during this process (see my answer above) especially if other workloads are in progress.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain thank you for your time and answer, I have used partitioner, hashset and return (as you pointed, and I think this did the trick) everything went smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The bulk of my answer is less-so an answer to your question and more some guidance - if you were to provide some more technical details, I may be able to assist more precisely.

A `Parallel.ForEach` is probably not the best solution here -- especially when you have a shared list or a busy server.

You are locking to write but not to read from that shared list.  So I'm surprised it's not throwing during the Where.  Turn the `List<string>` into a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool>` (just to create a simple concurrent hash table) then you'll get better write throughput and it won't throw during reads.

But you're going to have **database contention issues** (if using multiple connections) because your insert will likely still require locks.  Even if you simply split the workload you would run into this.  This DB locking could cause blocks/deadlocks so it may end up slower than the original.  If using one connection, you generally cannot parallelize commands.

I would try wrapping the majority of inserts in a **transaction** containing **batches** of say 1000 inserts or place the entire workload into one bulk insert.  Then the database will keep the data in-memory and commit the entire thing to disk when finished (instead of one record at a time).

Depending on your typical workload, you may want to try different storage solutions.  Databases are *generally* bad for inserting large volumes of records... you will likely see much better performance with alternative solutions (such as Key-Value stores).  Or place the data into something like Redis and slowly persist to the database in the background.

Comment: thank you for your precious input. since I am not modifying source list but the list that I am comparing, there are no collection modified errors occur. On the other hand, I am not able to update db on bulk means as you suggested, since I am using entity framework with efcache module, so outer ef transactions out of question.